# Effect of Application crash on acquired DB locks

Tags: java, hibernate

In my application I need to acquire DB locks on a row.

I'm using the Hibernate Framework, and I use the `LockOptions.UPGRADE`.
What would happen if my application goes down after it has acquired lock?.

I have tested a scenario where in I have abruptly shutdown my application server after the lock is acquired and then tried to initiate a request. I found no effect on the new request due lock acquired before when the application server was shut down.

Are the locks acquired at Hibernate in its cache or at the DB level?
Are the locks released when such situation occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate does not lock in memory. You should consider `LockOptions.UPGRADE` as executing a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, ie. an actual DB locking operation.

As such, I'd expect that it's very much implementation dependent how an acquired lock is released if your client "goes away", but most RDBMS' *will* have some keepalive timeout and/or other detection of stale connections.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what RDBMS engine you're using, if you're using a RDMS engine that is. Hibernate does not lock objects in memory. Your application can expect the behavior as defined by the isolation level of your database transactions.

The cache is used for queries done on tables that don't change very often(if at all), and, of course, for read only stuff which doesn't require any locks.

Most RDBMS are transaction-based, or to be more specific, 'all-or-nothing'. If the query doesn't finish succesfully for whatever reason, nothing happens and all resources allocated that query uses are released.